# ZSH Terminal: Can't find tmux.cnf file

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh

I've installed Tmux in my Arch Linux GNOME system and for changing keybinds. I need to configure `.tmux.cnf`, but I can't find it. I searched for `~/.tmux.cnf`, `/etc/tmux.cnf` or `/etc/.tmux.cnf` and seeing nothing.

I hope someone can solve this.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldnt be looking for tmux.conf instead of tmux.cnf ?

Comment: Hi Silbee thanks for the response!

Yes, you're right, but... I tried also with .conf and also had nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I searched for ~/.tmux.cnf, /etc/tmux.cnf or /etc/.tmux.cnf and seeing nothing.

You should be looking for `tmux.conf`. However:

> There is no default `/etc/tmux.conf` file. You can start with the
> example conf files in `/usr/share/doc/tmux/examples`, or look at the
> manual/web/etc. to come up with your own configuration file.
>
> The `examples` directory contains:
>
> ```
> /usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/n-marriott.conf
> /usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/t-williams.conf
> /usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/vim-keys.conf
> /usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/h-boetes.conf
> /usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/screen-keys.conf
> ```

Source: [Ask Ubuntu Where is the default tmux.conf file located?](https://askubuntu.com/a/192407/376050) answer by [ish](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/ish)

Comment: You can also have a look at the Arch specific wiki entry for tmux at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/tmux

Comment: Hi David thanks for responding! There's no tmux directory in that route.

Comment: Did you read the rest of the answer? You have to write your own.

Comment: I'm sorry David! Okay, I'll do the configuration file and see if it works, thanks!

Comment: It works! Added `/etc/tmux.conf` with an keybind change and worked, thanks for the help DavidPostill.